# Let $P$ be a point on $DE$ and let the extensions of $BP$ and $CP$ meet the sides $AC$ and $AB$ at $G$ and $F$ respectively.

Tags: geometry, triangles, problem-solving

> In $\Delta ABC$ , $AB = AC = 1$ and $D,E$ are midpoints of $AB$ and $AC$ respectively. Let $P$ be a point on $DE$ and let the extensions of $BP$ and $CP$ meet the sides $AC$ and $AB$ at $G$ and $F$ respectively. Find $\frac{1}{BF} + \frac{1}{CG}$ .

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

If we take $P$ at either ends like $D$ or $E$ then we get $BF = 0.5$ cm and $CG = 1$ cm . From here I get that $\frac{1}{BF} + \frac{1}{CG} = 3$ . But the surprising thing is wherever I choose $P$ the answer is always coming $3$ in Geogebra. I cannot understand how that is coming.

Can someone explain why the value is always constant? Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{GE}{GC} = \frac{PE}{BC}$ (by similar triangles $\triangle GPE, \triangle GBC$)

Similarly,

$\frac{FD}{FB} = \frac{PD}{BC}$

Adding both,

$\frac{GE}{GC} + \frac{FD}{FB} = \frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{GC-EC}{GC} + \frac{FB-BD}{FB} = \frac{1}{2}$

$2 - \frac{EC}{GC} - \frac{BD}{FB} = \frac{1}{2}$

As $EC = BD = \frac{1}{2}$

We get $\frac{1}{GC} + \frac{1}{FB} = 3$

Comment: Got it, so I had to use similarity in order to find the solution.

Comment: @Anonymous yes that is correct.  $\triangle GPE \sim \triangle GBC$ and $\triangle FDP \sim \triangle FBC$. That leads to the ratios.

Comment: Btw where do you get such nice diagrams? Not this one but most others with colors?

Comment: Hmm? I just draw them in paint.

Comment: Nice! I need to learn that.